# Weblogo - selenocysteine alphabet

Tags: console, bioinformatics, biopython

I want to generate logo with selenocysteine, but when i choose option with reduced_protein_alphabet i get error 'Repetative alphabet'

```
weblogo -f sc.txt -D fasta -o sc_logo -F pdf -a reduced_protein_alphabet -s large -n 100 -c chemistry
```

Comment: cross posted: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2661

Comment: Can you add your input file?

Comment: sorry i can't, it is not confidential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:
Here what i've done

1. Check if the infile do not have errors.
2. add a alphabet 'ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVUWY' to option -a
3. color aminoacids in this alphabet -C

   weblogo -f sc.txt -D fasta -o logo -F pdf -n 100 -A protein -a 'ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVUWY' -s large -C yellow U selenocysteine -C red DE acidic -C black AVLIPWFM Hydrophobic -C blue KRH basic  -C purple QN Neutral -C green GSTYC Polar

I didn't realese it is that simple. Maybe it will help someone!